# nested inits in protocol extension

Tags: swift, initialization, protocols

Consider a protocol defining multiple initializers, all but one implemented in a protocol extension.

For this example Xcode doesn't show any errors or warnings but trying to build it fails with `Command /.../swiftc failed with exit code 1`. Running it as a script causes a segfault.

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var values: [Int] { get }

    init(_ values: Int...)
    init(_ values: [Int])
    init(_ values: Int..., offset: Int)
    init(_ values: [Int], offset: Int)
}

extension MyProtocol {
    init(_ values: Int...) {
        self.init(values)
    }

    init(_ values: [Int]) {
        self.init(values, offset: values.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 } / values.count)
    }

    init(_ values: Int..., offset: Int) {
        self.init(values, offset: offset)
    }
}

struct MyStruct: MyProtocol {
    let values: [Int]

    init(_ values: [Int], offset: Int) {
        self.values = values.map { $0 - offset }
    }
}

let myStruct = MyStruct([1, 2, 3])
```

I realize that only the last `init` (the one implemented by the struct itself) should really be part of the protocol (and it works fine that way) but it'd like to understand what exactly causes the compiler to explode if they are included?

Comment: The answer to any question "why does the compiler crash" is always "a compiler bug." The compiler should never crash, regardless of the input. Any time you can crash the compiler, you should submit a radar (bugreport.apple.com).

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the declaration of the three initialisers with default implementation in the protocol, you can just remove them and everything works as expected:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var values: [Int] { get }

    init(_ values: [Int], offset: Int)
}
```